# Slow JQuery Mobile panels in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, panel

I'm implementing a slide panel in JQM for a Phonegap application, but for some reason when I open try opening it on Android 4.x it takes 1500ms to appear, but in Android 2.x, iOS and Blackberry it shows instantaneously.

```
$(document).on("touchstart","img#openLeft", function()
{
     $('#mydiv').panel("toggle");
}
```

Could you please tell me what strategy can I follow to make the panel appear faster, without removing the sliding animation?

Thanks!

PS I am using JQuery Mobile 1.3.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up modifying JQM-1.3.0.css to fix this problem, turns out they were not hardware accelerated.

on:

- @-webkit-keyframes slideinfromright
- @-moz-keyframes slideinfromright
- @keyframes slideinfromright
- @-webkit-keyframes slideinfromleft
- @-moz-keyframes slideinfromleft
- @keyframes slideinfromleft
- @-webkit-keyframes slideouttoleft
- @-moz-keyframes slideouttoleft
- @keyframes slideouttoleft
- @-webkit-keyframes slideouttoright
- @-moz-keyframes slideouttoright
- @keyframes slideouttoright
- .slide.out
- .slide.in
- .slide.out.reverse
- .slide.in.reverse

I changed all the `-webkit-transform: translateX(x);` for `-webkit-transform: translate3d(x,0,0);`

and I also changed my animation to `data-display="push"` which seems to work faster than `data-display="reveal"` because it starts the animation while translating instead of waiting for the content to translate and show it afterwards.

Comment: +1 for data-display to push. This made a massive difference for me, without losing the animation.

Answer (score 0):

As given by documentation, these are accelerated by hardware. May be your 4.0 device is under-performing.

You can disable animation by adding `data-animate="false"` to pane's div. It is mentioned in the [documentation](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/panels/).

Comment: Seems like the documentation is wrong, it is NOT hardware accelerated. I posted the solution on this same thread.