# Very slow reaction of clicking the panel or no reaction at all - Phonegap 2.9 + JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, panel

I am developing a mobile application using PhoneGap 2.9 for Android in Eclipse.
I've read many other StackOverflow questions about the panels such as [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673526/slow-jquery-mobile-panels-in-phonegap) one. 
Because my application requires wi-fi to let someone use it, I haven't download JQuery, but I call them from my .html file:

```
    <!-- import js --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

In the above link, one answer says to edit the `.css` of JQuery so I couldn't do it.

---

As I read in another post related to this problem, I created a JavaScript which I call right after the import of JQuery. It's content:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition   = 'none';
        $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
        $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;
    }
```

---

My `.html` code related to the panel is this:

```
        <div id="leftHead"> 
            <a href="#menu"><img src="../../imgs/menu.png"></a>
        </div>

  <!-- defaultpanel  -->
  <div data-role="panel" id="menu" data-theme="b" data-display="push" data-animate:"false">

    <div class="panel-content">
        <h3>Default panel options</h3>
        <a href="">Option One</a><br/>
        <a href="">Option Two</a><br/>
        <a href="home.html" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-inline="true">Close panel</a>
    </div><!-- /content wrapper for padding -->
  </div><!-- /defaultpanel -->
```

---

When I press the image in the `lefthead` div, sometimes I get a really slow response and sometimes no panel opens after the click. Can anyone help me so that I can make this simple function much faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tested it using Fastclick library?

https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Comment: Thank you now it's really fast.